# How to iterate over list of lists and select random element in every list?

Tags: python

I have list of lists and I need to iterate over it and select one element in every list. And I need to do it 10 times.
This is example of my code:

```
from itertools import chain
import random
test_list = [[4, 5, 5], [2, 7, 4], [8, 6, 3]]
```

I tried:

```
for element in range(10):
    for element in list:
        res = random.choice(list(chain.from_iterable(test_list)))
        print("Random number from Matrix : " + str(res))
```

But I got error: `'type' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problems

- you declare `element` twice as the iteration variable
- you iterate on `list` which is a Python type, you need to iterate on `test_list`
- you need to pick an element of the current sublist of the iteration, not the whole `test_list`

---

#### Solution

```
import random

test_list = [[4, 5, 5], [2, 7, 4], [8, 6, 3]]

for i in range(10):
    print(f"Round {i}")
    for sublist in test_list:
        res = random.choice(sublist)
        print("Random number from Matrix :", res)
```

---

Giving something like

```
Round 0
Random number from Matrix : 5
Random number from Matrix : 7
Random number from Matrix : 6
Round 1
Random number from Matrix : 5
Random number from Matrix : 4
Random number from Matrix : 8
Round 2
Random number from Matrix : 5
Random number from Matrix : 4
Random number from Matrix : 8
Round 3
Random number from Matrix : 5
Random number from Matrix : 7
Random number from Matrix : 3
...
```

Comment: Thank you all, it works. But could you say me what is wrong with error which I got try your code with my data ```object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()``` , please? When I tried to do ```res = random.choice(sublist)```?

Comment: Because my data looks like: [14598 12932 14186 10402]
[10520 15400 16021 17639 15684 14695]
[19011 14676 15288 19173 13119 19114 12128 11827]...

Comment: @Greck9 do `print(type(test_list), type(test_list[0]), type(test_list[0][0]))` with your real data to ensure it shows you `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.int32'>`

Comment: I used ```hlthy_ar = np.asarray(test_list)``` to get ```<class 'numpy.ndarray>```, beacuse it was ```class list```,  but after that I tried ```type(test_list[0][0])``` and I got ```invalid index to scalar variable```

Comment: @Greck9 you don't have a 2D array in fact, but a 1D array, there is a problem with your data

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to chain here at all, because you're picking an item from each of the inner lists. Also, you're trying to iterate over `list`, which is a type, instead of `test_list`.

```
for _ in range(10):
    for inner_list in test_list:
        print("Random number from Matrix:", random.choice(inner_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

something like the below

```
import random

test_list = [[4, 5, 5], [2, 7, 4], [8, 6, 3]]

for _ in range(10):
    for lst in test_list:
        print(lst[random.randint(0, len(lst) - 1)])
```